# Automatically share (post) a website's news post also to a specific Facebook Page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have built an admin interface where admin users can create short news update posts. I've created a Facebook Page where these news posts should also be posted when the admin saves the post. The people posting have been made admins of the specific Facebook Page.

**Edit: I've since gotten the below code running, and my current problem is finding the fault with Facebook returning a NULL session, since it doesn't fire an exception nor causes an error message.**

*This is where I started (old info):*

*I've followed this guide http://www.pontikis.net/blog/auto_post_on_facebook_with_php
I'm stuck at two points: Create App step 3 (publishing for all presumable takes it out of the no longer existing Sandbox mode, but I've not found any Canvas URL. I've set the Canvas URL to the index.php where I will insert the code in the example).
The other point is Facebook Access Token step 2. I'm pasting the example URL, but instead of getting the $GET array I get a dialog from Facebook, which I've followed **but it seems Facebook thinks I'm creating an app for their appstore**, and it "needs screenshots" before permitting my two permissions. Well, I need the permissions before I can "Submit for review" by Facebook staff, so something is seriously wrong.*

To me, since my web admins will be told to be logged in to Facebook, I'm looking for an **alternative way** to do the same thing. Is there an on-line service that takes a headline and text in a httppost URL and posts it, perhaps with a Facebook app they've already created? For all I know, Facebook may take a URL with such parameters (or a Javascript snippet as for the Like buttons) but I haven't come across it in my searches yet.

Or, you could help point out what's wrong in that guide. **Edit: or what's wrong with this code. $session is NULL, no exception fired.** My app is set and I got the correct id etc values from the Graph API console, and I'm logged into Facebook.

```
session_start();
require_once 'autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCanvasLoginHelper;

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'myappid','mysecret' );

$helper = new FacebookCanvasLoginHelper();
try {
    $session = $helper->getSession();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
}

if ($session) {
    $access_token = "myaccesstoken";
    $page_id="mypageid";
    // post to page
    $page_post = (new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/'. $page_id .'/feed', array(
        'access_token' => $access_token,
        'name' => 'AVIA',
        'link' => 'http://avia.se',
        'caption' => 'Caption blah blah...',
        'message' => 'Message!',
      ) ))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray();

} else {
    die("NO SESSION!");
}
```

I just don't see why I can't get the Facebook session with a one-liner when I'm logged in.

Comment: You don’t need to submit for review to ask anyone that has a role in the app (admin/developer/tester) for any permissions – so you can develop your app, and only once the functionality is implemented and tested you submit for review. (If the app is not suposed to be used by the general public, then you might not need to submit for review in any case, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#apps-all-users-are-developers)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the main problem - everyone makes their own solution and app type, and none of those are among the limited and much simpler examples in the docs. In this case, neither Canvas URL nor the index.php test-call to get the code is necessary, I seem to have found out. From this newer guide. https://www.webniraj.com/2014/08/23/facebook-api-posting-as-a-page-using-graph-api-v2-x-and-php-sdk-4-0-x/

Comment: I got the necessary values from the Graph API "console" manually. I was able to get actual code actually running from an actually complete example. Right now I'm stuck at getting a session back from Facebook. NULL returned, no error message. Yay.